# FireBase RecyclerView horizontal scrool

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of job storage in firebase realtime database, I want to know how can I display recycler view in this way: 
Screenshot:
[image]

(1/10) Number of Job in firebase storage

Comment: can u explain little more, as provided info is very less to solve your problem

Comment: Inside of display data into simple recycleView in the same page i want everypage contain it own data like exactly recycleView but horizontal way every data in New page

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display data in horizontal way you can use horizontal recycler view, set layout manager as follows

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

But if you want to show as page then consider using [viewpager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide)

Comment: no i mean every item in single page

Comment: you see the screen above, 1/10 everyitem into single page (1 is one job stored in firebase )

Comment: i have updated the answer, you can use view pager, is it that what you are looking for?

Comment: View pager with dynamnic Number of page depend on Firebase Storage i didn't find solution

Comment: You'll have to write logic of pagination with firebase firestore, check the link for pagination https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors